# Looking for LogFormat for awstats to read my custom apache logfiles

Tags: apache-2.4, awstats

My apache-2.4 LogFormat:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b ref=\"%{Referer}i\" ua=\"%{User-Agent}i\" host=\"%{Host}i\" xff=\"%{X-Forwarded-for}i\""
```

Sample Logfile line for reference:

```
"10.10.10.200 - - [29/Jan/2017:03:45:15 +0100] "GET /health-check/97b0d3c3dd9cfaf7f532aed814f2a049 HTTP/1.0" 200 19 ref="-" ua="-" host="10.10.10.10" xff="-""
```

My problem seems to be to get the IPs that are written here `host="10.10.10.10"` into the %host variable for awstats. I think it's because of the quotes around the IP. As you can see I've tried to quote the quotes, but that doesn't seem to work. So I am basically looking for a away to tell awstats that the IP is in double quotes and it should write that IP into the %host variable.

My tries for awstats `LogFormat` so far (+ some slight variation on these).
*On early tries I still thought the first column had the right IP for me, which is not the case*:

```
#LogFormat="%host - - %time1 %methodurl %code %bytesd ref=%refererquot ua=%uaquot host=\"%extra1\" xff=\"%extra2\""
#LogFormat="%host %other %other %time1 %methodurl %code %bytesd %refererquot %uaquot %other %other"
#LogFormat="%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b ref=\"%{Referer}i\" ua=\"%{User-Agent}i\" host=\"%{Host}i\" xff=\"%{X-Forwarded-for}i\""
#LogFormat="%host - - %time1 %methodurl %code %bytesd %refererquot %uaquot \"%extra1\" \"%extra2\""
#LogFormat="%other - - %time1 %methodurl %code %bytesd ref="-" ua=%uaquot host=\"%host\" xff=%otherquot"
#LogFormat='%other - - %time1 %methodurl %code %bytesd ref="-" ua=%uaquot host="%host" xff=%otherquot'
```

Errors I get are either:

```
Error: Your personalized LogFormat does not include all fields required by AWStats (Add %host in your LogFormat string).
```

or

```
AWStats did not find any valid log lines that match your LogFormat parameter, in the 50th first non commented lines read of your log.
```

Or I might be on the completely wrong path here, in which case I am open for suggestions ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is what i came up with in the end:

```
LogFormat="%other - - %time1 %methodurl %code %bytesd ref=\"%referer\" ua=\"%ua\" host=%host xff=%extra1"
```

Apparently using `%uaquote` and `%refererquot` was misleading because it didn't work for me with double quotes as I thought it would.
And the only way to get the real host into awstats was to use `host=%host`, which means that the hosts are now double quoted in awstats.